# How to implement path aliases in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to find a way to implement route aliases in Angular.js using `ui-router`.

Let's say I have a state with the url `article/:articleId` and I want to have `/articles/some-article-title` redirected (internally) to `/article/76554` without changing the browser location.

Could this be done with `ui-router`?

Answer (score 14):

#### I. Doubled state mapping (reuse of controller, views)

*NOTE: This is original answer, showing how to solve the issue with two states. Below is another approach, reacting on the comment by [Geert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637423/geert)*

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFoMJckH4283law0wqgE?p=preview) with working example. Say we have this two objects (on a server)

```
var articles = [
  {ID: 1, Title : 'The cool one', Content : 'The content of the cool one',},
  {ID: 2, Title : 'The poor one', Content : 'The content of the poor one',},
];
```

And we would like to use URL as

```
// by ID
../article/1
../article/2

// by Title
../article/The-cool-one
../article/The-poor-one
```

Then we can create this state definitions:

```
// the detail state with ID
.state('articles.detail', {
    url: "/{ID:[0-9]{1,8}}",
    templateUrl: 'article.tpl.html',
    resolve : {
      item : function(ArticleSvc, $stateParams) {

        return ArticleSvc.getById($stateParams.ID);
      },
    },
    controller:['$scope','$state','item',
      function ( $scope , $state , item){ 

        $scope.article = item;
    }],
  })

// the title state, expecting the Title to be passed
.state('articles.title', {
    url: "/{Title:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]*}",
    templateUrl: 'article.tpl.html',
    resolve : {
      item : function(ArticleSvc, $stateParams) {

        return ArticleSvc.getByTitle($stateParams.Title);
      },
    },
    controller:['$scope','$state','item',
      function ( $scope , $state , item){ 

        $scope.article = item;
    }],
  })
```

As we can see, the trick is that the **Controller** and the **Template** *(templateUrl)* are the same. We just ask the Service `ArticleSvc` to `getById()` or `getByTitle()`. Once resolved, we can work with the returned item...

The plunker with more details is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFoMJckH4283law0wqgE?p=preview)

#### II. Aliasing, based on native `UI-Router` functionality

*Note: This extension reacts on [Geert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637423/geert) appropriate comment*

So, there is a `UI-Router` built-in/native way for route aliasing. It is called

#### [$urlRouterProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider) - .when()

I created working [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOZw4gHQh025FjFTPAKZ?p=preview). Firstly, we will need only **one** state defintion, but without any restrictions on ID.

```
.state('articles.detail', {
    //url: "/{ID:[0-9]{1,8}}",
    url: "/{ID}",
```

We also have to implement some mapper, converting title to id *(the alias mapper)*. That would be new Article service method:

```
var getIdByTitle = function(title){
   // some how get the ID for a Title
   ...
}
```

And now the power of `$urlRouterProvider.when()`

```
 $urlRouterProvider.when(/article\/[a-zA-Z\-]+/,
  function($match, $state, ArticleSvc) {

    // get the Title 
    var title = $match.input.split('article/')[1];
    // get some promise resolving that title
    // converting it into ID
    var promiseId = ArticleSvc.getIdByTitle(title);

    promiseId.then(function(id){

      // once ID is recieved... we can go to the detail
      $state.go('articles.detail', { ID: id}, {location: false}); 
    })

    // essential part! this will instruct UI-Router, 
    // that we did it... no need to resolve state anymore
    return true;
  }
);
```

That's it. This simple implementation skips error, wrong title... handling. But that is expected to be implemented anyhow... [Check it here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOZw4gHQh025FjFTPAKZ?p=preview)

Comment: This is not an alias of any sort, but just two state-configurations that look very similar (and indeed reuse the same template)

Comment: @Geert thanks for your comment. Your point is correct and valid. It helped me to extend the answer and to show another way, how to solve "Alias" needs. Would say, that this could suite to you a bit more... *NOTE: Thanks a lot for your comment and bravery. Only that approach (leaving a comment) could help to improve the answers. Amazing!*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution saved me from a lot of head banging and hair pulling today :)

Comment: Is there any way to do it with angular2+ ?