# Can I pass a variable into the controller using UI-Router & ui-sref?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was wondering if it was possible to pass multiple variables through the UI-Router to be used in a state's controller.

In the HTML, I have

```
<li class="blist-item grid-loader" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ui-sref="item({ id: {{item.$id}} })"><h3>{{item.title}}</h3></a>
</li>
```

And in the configuration, I have:

```
.state('item', {
        url: '/item/:id',
        templateUrl: 'templates/single/single-main.html',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        $scope.item.$id = $stateParams.id;
    }
})
```

Now, the above configuration works, but the problem is that each item's unique ID is an incomprehensible string that leaves me with links such as  "/item/-sds43sd_23s".

What I am trying to figure out is:
  
  
(1) how to have the URL be directed to the item title, 
  
  
(2) while also using the item's ID as the primary method for getting the item object's data.
  
  
Is there a way I can pass both variables (the item's ID & the item's title) through to the router?

Comment: Are all of your titles going to be unique also?

Comment: Yes, each title will be uniquely associated to each ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, there is a solution for your issue. This Q & A should solve it: [How to implement path aliases in ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23830421/1679310). There is a link to that [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOZw4gHQh025FjFTPAKZ?p=preview).

We would need this state definition *(exactly as in above snippet)* which does not restrict id anyhow (e.g. [Regex Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters) {id:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}} this would avoid passing title...)

```
.state('item', {
    url: '/item/:id', // no restrcitions, this is what we need
    ...
```

Next step is to have a `service` which is able to get ID by title

```
.factory('ItemSvc', ...
  // some service, converting title into ID
  ...
  var getIdByTitle = function(title){
     // some how get the ID for a Title
     ...
  }
```

Finally, we will use `UI-Router` feature [$urlRouterProvider - .when()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider)

```
$urlRouterProvider.when(/item\/[a-zA-Z\-]+/,
  function($match, $state, ItemSvc) {

    // get the Title 
    var title = $match.input.split('item/')[1];
    // get some promise resolving that title
    // converting it into ID
    var promiseId = ItemSvc.getIdByTitle(title);

    promiseId.then(function(id){

      // once ID is recieved... we can go to the detail
      $state.go('item', {id: id}, {location: false}); 
    })

    // essential part! this will instruct UI-Router, 
    // that we did it... no need to resolve state anymore
    return true;
  }
);
```

Check the [example in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOZw4gHQh025FjFTPAKZ?p=preview)

Comment: Hey @Radim, this comment is long overdue, but after a little fiddling, your code definitely lead me to the right answer. Thank you so so much for the time you spent answering this!

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy amazing tool `UI-Router` ;)