# Use an articles title in the url, not the id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angular-ui-router

I have a list of links which leads to different articles.
They look something like this:

```
<a ui-sref="post-view({ id: post._id })">...</a>
```

And they produce hrefs like this: `href="/blog/546cb8af0c0ec394d7fbfdbf"`, which is what it is supposed to do. When I click the link, I go to the relevant article with the id `546cb8af0c0ec394d7fbfdbf`.

However, I think having the id in the url like that is less userfriendly than having the title of the article, which is what I want. But I can't think of a good way to do it.

Since an articles title not necessarily are unique, I don't know how to get the correct article from the database based on the title (which isn't possible, I need something unique to look it up by).

I've build the site on node, with mongodb, express, and angular. For routing I use the angular ui-router project.

This is how the routing looks in ui.router:

```
.state('post-view', {
    url: '/blog/:id',
    templateUrl: '/post',
    controller: 'post'
})
```

As you can see, I use the `:id` in the url, which I access in the `post` controller.

If I was supposed to show the article on the same page, as a sub state of the currently active state, I could have inherited the id from the parent state, but since this leads to a new page, I'm not sure what I could do.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Maybe this [Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853129/1679310) could also give you some hints..

Comment: Nice, skimmed through it. Will have a close look.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use a slug. A slug is a URL friendly version of a title,

Title: My Hero Post

Slug: /my-hero-post

Example of WordPress ad some replacement whenever it creates a slug from a title:

Documentation: [wp_unique_post_slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug)

[Source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3668)

What you need to do is to replace characters like `å` or `/` in your title with something URL friendly and replace spaces with `-` and then save that as a unique key in your post object when you are creating the post. You can also have a look at the ghost source code for an example:

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/d44a97405bbe58730f3c397f504634a504d3e6e9/core/server/models/base.js#L322

This NPM package actually does most of the work for you: [slugify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/slugify)

Comment: I was thinking about the way Wordpress do this actually, but for some reason I thought I'd make some sort of mapping between title and id. I don't know why I didn't think slugs, I know Wordpress use them. Thanks, I'll check this out later, when I have time!

Comment: It helped :) If there are identical slugs, I suppose I could just add a number at the end of the slug.

Comment: That's also what WordPress and Ghost do actually :)

Comment: I agree with Jonathan M. Hethey that a slug is a good solution. But because of the fact that this slug is a refinment of the title – which I guess is **changeable** – you end up with a identifier which needs to be updated when the title is updated. 

And maybe you even will use this identifier as a reference in other documents. And if this identifier is not immutable, you have to change all references along with possible changes to the title/slug. This might require several non atomic operations if the data is spread in several collections. 

Just some things to consider =)

Comment: Regarding the possible problem with identical slugs... you can as you say add a number, or just reject new article with a title that give rise to a slug that is already taken. Either you let Mongo handle this with unique indexes, or you do a client side check for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation to you is to not use the name of the article in the url if you can not guarantee that the name is unique and will not change or be edit in the future.

Because in this situation you will have to manage all previous names and point them to the correct url with 301 redirect code for SEO purposes and you will also have to convert special characters that can't perform in the URL.

So I take it you do not want to use the _id that Mongodb make for you and you can make your id yourself. start with 1 and check each time what was the last number and increase it by one

Comment: So that the ids will be a number, e.g. 45? Hmm, I'll think about it. It might look a little bit better, but it would be nice to have the title there. Maybe I have to change something more fundamental.

Comment: I would not recommend setting `_id` to an incremental number **unless** you have a good reason for it. MongoDB lack built in self-incrementing functionality, and therefore you have to manually [set up a counter collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) in the DB and `findAndModify` this each time you need new number(s). This is by no means impossible, but require a litte extra work. A UID (or basically an ObjecId...) is is easier and require no memorization.