# StateProvider that appends a label to the URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to append a user-recognizable URL to the end of the url through $stateProvider.

For example with StackOverflow's questions, it goes stackoverflow.com/questions/(question_id)/(question title). I'd like to achieve that in my URL just by getting the question_id and then append a phrase accordingly. Any ideas?

```
$stateProvider
  .state('question', {
    url: '/question/:qid',
    templateUrl: 'q.htm',
    controller:'bla'
    resolve: {
        title: function($http, $stateParams){
            return $http.get('title/'+$stateParams.qid);
        }
    }
  });
```

Then somehow append the title to the url.

Comment: *Just a hint - some solution could be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23830421/1679310)*

Comment: ^Great lead. Didn't think of $urlRouterProvider. I'll get back with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I came up with was:  ( [click 'Locations' and the table row on this demo](http://tak215.github.io/angular-architecture/dashboard.html) )

Added id, name parameter within $stateProvider.state

```
url: "location/:lid/:name",
```

But when 'lid' was not specified, 'name' would not be specified either so, the URL would show 'location//' so, in that case, make lid = 'all' and name = '' so it would 'tell' the controller to show all locations, not a specific one.

```
lid: function($stateParams){
    $stateParams.lid = $stateParams.lid || 'all';
    return $stateParams.lid;
},
```

Then make lid as a dependency and inject into getName. (I'm using $q as an altenative to $http to show promise works great here for the next dependency) Notice the randomized timeout time.

```
getName: ['$q','$timeout','lid', function($q, $timeout, lid){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
        var names = ['Cool Place', 'Awesome place', 'boring place', 'I want to be here', 'Random Venue'];
        deferred.resolve(names[ parseInt(lid) % 4 ]);
    }, Math.round(Math.random()*200));

return deferred.promise;
}],
```

Then inject getName and lid into name:

```
name : ['lid', '$state','$stateParams','getName', function (lid, $state, $stateParams,getName) {
    if($stateParams.lid.length < 1 || $stateParams.lid == 'all'){ // show all or not set Location ID
        $stateParams.name = '';
        return '';
    }
    if($stateParams.name.length > 0){ // if the name is already specified, it's ok. settle
        return $stateParams.name;
    }

    // hyphens are better than %20 in the url
    getName = getName.replace(/\s/g,'-');

    $state.transitionTo('dashboard.location', {lid:lid, name:getName}, {
        reload:true,
        inherit:false,
        notify:true
        })
}]
```

If the name is not in the parameters already, then transition with a 'reload' property set to true.

Done. here's the demo ( [click 'Locations' and the table row on this demo](http://tak215.github.io/angular-architecture/dashboard.html) )

**To put everything together:**

```
.state('dashboard.location', {
            templateUrl : "apps/location/template/location_template.htm",
            controller: 'LocationCtrl',
            url: "location/:lid/:name",
            resolve: {
                ctrl: function($ocLazyLoad){
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: "dashboard.location",
                        files: ['apps/location/location_controller.js', 'apps/location/style/location.css']
                    });
                },
                lid: function($stateParams){
                    $stateParams.lid = $stateParams.lid || 'all';

                    return $stateParams.lid;
                },
                getName: ['$q','$timeout','lid', function($q, $timeout, lid){
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $timeout(function() {
                        var names = ['Cool Place', 'Awesome place', 'boring place', 'I want to be here', 'Random Venue'];
                        deferred.resolve(names[ parseInt(lid) % 4 ]);
                    }, Math.round(Math.random()*200));
                    return deferred.promise;
                }],
                name : ['lid', '$state','$stateParams','getName', function (lid, $state, $stateParams,getName) {

                    if($stateParams.lid.length < 1 || $stateParams.lid == 'all'){ // show all or not set Location ID
                        $stateParams.name = '';
                        return '';
                    }
                    if($stateParams.name.length > 0){ // if the name is already specified, it's ok. settle
                        return $stateParams.name;
                    }

                    // hyphens are better than %20 in the url
                    getName = getName.replace(/\s/g,'-');

                    $state.transitionTo('dashboard.location', {lid:lid, name:getName}, {
                        reload:true,
                        inherit:false,
                        notify:true
                    })
                }]
            }
        })
```

I hope this helps others.