# AngularJs UI router - one state with multiple URLs

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a request to add in another URL parameter that directs to a state that I already have set up. For efficiency purposes, I'm trying to see if I can add multiple URLs to point to the same state, or should I just use the $UrlRouterProvider.when() method to re-direct to that state in this new case.

Ex. this is what already exists

```
.state('site.link1',
  {
    url: '/link1',
    templateUrl: '/views/link1.html',
    controller: 'link1Ctrl'
  })
```

and the request is to add www.site.com/newlink that points to the link1 page. Is there something like this;

```
.state('site.link1',
  {
    url: '/link1, /newlink',
    ...
```

Comment: Currently you'd have to use either .when or define state multi times, with different url... there is some how to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853129/1679310

Comment: if the only change is the stateParams you can get away with the same route and just passing empty param, the only  thing that is not so elegant is that you'll have a "//" in your url. if the spec is defining a completely different url then a new state is needed

Comment: if 2 different param value on the same state redirects to these different ursl then you can use templateurl as a function where you get first argument as routeparam and return the url accordingly. but it is little unclear on what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 16):

Try using the Regex and a parameter in the url. It is not optimal but works.

```
.state('site.link1',
 {
   url: '/{path:link1|newlink}',
   templateUrl: '/views/link1.html',
   controller: 'link1Ctrl'
 })
```

[More information on regex in Urls](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher).

To generate links with `ui-sref` pass the same parameter with the state name as a function

```
<a ui-sref="site.link1({path:'link1'})" >site link 1</a>
<a ui-sref="site.link1({path:'newlink'})">site new link</a>
```

Answer (score 15):

You use params:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

```
.state('site.link',
{
    url: '/{link}'
    ..
}
```

so when you use the same state like this

```
$state.go('site.link', {link: 'link1'})
$state.go('site.link', {link: 'link2'})
```

Comment: i'm curious, where did you see such an example in the link you provide ?

Comment: The link show the documentation and it uses contacts.details. I just use this example to show how to change state using "go" function.

Answer (score 11):

you can used [`when()`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#when-for-redirection)  function

```
.state('site.link1',
  {
    url: '/link1',
    templateUrl: '/views/link1.html',
    controller: 'link1Ctrl'
  })
```

then on root config

```
angular.module('myApp', [...])
   .config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
       $urlRouterProvider.when(/newlink/, ['$state','$match', function ($state, $match) {
           $state.go('site.link1');
       }]);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this approach to be quite simple and clean: create two equal states, just changing the `url` property

```
//Both root and login are the same, but with different url's.
var rootConfig = {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl:'html/authentication/login.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl',
    data: {
        requireLogin: false
    }
}

var loginConfig = Object.create(rootConfig)
loginConfig.url = '/login'

$stateProvider
    .state('root', rootConfig)
    .state('login', loginConfig)
```

Comment: Well, isn't this example for two states? Would there be an instance where we can override the state's `url` option? So, at the end, there will be just one state. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, only with another constraint - I didn't want to use a redirect, since I wanted the url in the browser to stay the same, but display the same state.
This was because I wanted the chrome saved passwords to work for users that already saved the previous url.

In my case I wanted these two urls :
`/gilly` and
`/new/gilly`
to both point to the same state.

I solved this by having one state defined for `/gilly`, and for the second url, I defined an abstract state called `/new`.

This should be set up like this :

```
$stateProvider.state('new', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/new'
    template: '',
    controller: function() { }
}).state('gilly', {
    url: '/gilly',
    template: 'gilly.html',
    controller: 'GillyController'
}).state('new.gilly', {
    url: '/gilly',  // don't add the '/new' prefix here!
    template: 'gilly.html',
    controller: 'GillyController'
});
```