# Creating pretty URLs for articles with Angular UI Router when articles have an ID

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My App queries an API to retrieve articles by an ID.

Here is my state configuration:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('article', {
        url: "/article/:articleId",
        templateUrl: 'article.html',
        controller: 'ArticleCtrl';
        }
    })
```

The resulting URL from retrieving a state like this is something like `http://domain.com/article/1234-5678-90`

This isn't a very pretty or memorable URL.

Is there an approach that would use the title of the article as a basis instead of the ID? (The API call that retrieves the article includes a title property).

Comment: *Just a hint, this is what I found so far as the closest to aliasing... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853129/1679310*

Comment: Sure, just change the url to `/article/:articleId/:articleTitle`. But make sure the actual title you pass in doesn't contain any special character, spaces, etc. just like the URL of this stackoverflow question does. That won't make the url memorable (nothing will), but it will make it prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use slugs, like **mysite.kom/articles/:id:/:slug:** which means something like **mysite.kom/articles/28272/my-article-title-is-a-slug**

Even better to put a date for the article:

**mysite.kom/articles/2014-04-03/28272/my-article-title-is-a-slug**

There is no way to make a long url rememberable, the good way is to make it SEO friendly and then maybe short it with url shortners

THIS
**mysite.kom/articles/2014-04-03/28272/my-article-title-is-a-slug**

TO THIS
**goo.gl/jnsf837fn**

Is probably the best you can achieve