# how to substitute the ID's in url with meaningful names in angular UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
angular.module('articles').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.
        state('viewArticle', {
            url: '/articles/:articleId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/articles/views/view-article.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

my angular UI router is like this. I want to substitute the articleId stateparams as article title for SEO purposes.

Comment: Check this [How to implement path aliases in ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23830421/1679310)

Comment: thanks  Radim Köhler . you saved my time.

Comment: hello  Radim Köhler, thats not my situation. in my situation i want to pass the artcleId from the view to the router as this .<a href="/articles/{{article._id}}">Read More..</a>    but I need to show the url as this. '/articles/title-of-the-article'.

Answer (score 0):

it's not important what is going to be written in the url address. you can just use this style `url: '/articles/:articleTitle'` and simply use a variable which contains your article title