# angular routing based on user action

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm a beginner in angular and I am trying to build an questionnaire app.
What I was trying to do is angular routing based on user action.
Say for example, in first page user have a question with three option. If user select option one and click next then the next question will be dependent on the option he/she selected in the first question. This behavior will be applied for all the questions.
Every time user click next with a option selected will redirect to a question based on his/her answer on last question.
I addition, also looking for a solution to show the number of the question(or the step number) he/she is in right now in the url. Like - question.com/questions/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the UI-Router. You can create a route and pass the data in the url. You can load the same route with different data and url. Load data inside your controller based on the [url](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing). check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830421/how-to-implement-path-aliases-in-ui-router/23853129#23853129).